# Increase height of UINavigationBar in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift5

I'm trying to change the height of UINavigationBar but without success, in particular I have to show three buttons with font size 50, and actually this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the first button it's been cut by navigation bar height, and it will be the same for the other ones. I've tried to add a subview inside the navigation bar but it still not working (text go outside the bar and the bar doesn't resize). Have you goto any advice or solution for this problem? I have seen that it's deprecated the possibility to change directly the height of the bar, but have you got some hacks?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't do that, you should rather reconsider your design... Maybe you can add a separated custom `UIView` subclass to the very top of the view? I would not include such high functionality directly in the Navigation Bar, especially not if you would need a hack to achieve your desired navigation bar. Apple has put much effort into its [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/), so I would also trust them with their Nav Bar height :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to subclass UINavigationBar and use that

```
class HeightedNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 104)
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement it in this way but it doesn't work; however i'll solve by creating a subclass of UIView

Comment: If it doesn't work, why did you accept the question as the correct one? This could be confusing for future readers.